# How can I reference a aws_cognito_user_pools id in `Terraform`?

Tags: terraform

I have below terraform configuration for cognito client:

```
data "aws_cognito_user_pools" "re_user_pool" {
  name = "${var.cognito_user_pool_name}"
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "app_client" {
  name = "re-app-client"

  user_pool_id = data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool.id
  depends_on   = [data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool]

  explicit_auth_flows                  = ["USER_PASSWORD_AUTH"]
  prevent_user_existence_errors        = "ENABLED"
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  allowed_oauth_flows                  = ["code"]
  allowed_oauth_scopes                 = ["phone", "openid", "email", "profile", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"]
  supported_identity_providers         = ["COGNITO", "Google"]
  callback_urls                        = ["https://scnothzsf0.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/staging/signup"]
}
```

I references the cognito user pool which already exists on AWS. The error happens on the line `user_pool_id = data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool.id` when it uses the user pool id in `aws_cognito_user_pool_client`. 
I will get the error

```
Error: Error creating Cognito User Pool Client: InvalidParameterException: 1 validation error detected: Value 're-user' at 'userPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\w-]+_[0-9a-zA-Z]+

  on infra/cognito.tf line 5, in resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "app_client":
   5: resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "app_client" {`
```

It seems the format of the ID is not correct. I have read this document `https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/cognito_user_pools.html` and it has a reference attribute `ids - The list of cognito user pool ids.`. I wonder why it gives a list of user pool id. How can I reference this ID?

I also tried to reference it as `user_pool_id = data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool.ids[0]` but got an error:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on infra/cognito.tf line 8, in resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "app_client":
   8:   user_pool_id = data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool.ids[0]

This value does not have any indices.
```

The `re_user_pool` referenced above is defined here:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "re_user_pool" {
  name = "re-user"
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first error: Could you post the `aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool` data source value?
Regarding the second one: it’s better to check the length of the list before you access certain indeces `user_pool_id = length(data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool.ids) > 0 ? data.aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool.ids[0] : <default_value>`

Comment: I added the length code and I get the same error. It means the length is greater than 0 but can't be accessed by index

Comment: If you got the same error (described in your question), I'd say your `aws_cognito_user_pools.re_user_pool` data source is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across your question while working through this same problem. I see the question is several months old, but I'm still going to add an answer for anyone else that ends up here like I did.

First, the solution is to convert the `ids` value from a `set` to a `list` via the `tolist` function and then access it as you would any terraform `list`.

**Caveat:** In my case, I have ensured I only have one user pool for a given name, but you could get multiple user pools if you haven't followed this convention. This solution will not be a complete solution for that situation, but perhaps it will still point in the right direction.

Example code:

```
data "aws_cognito_user_pools" "test" {
  name = "a_name"
}

output "test" {
  value = "${tolist(data.aws_cognito_user_pools.test.ids)[0]"
}
```

Second, how I arrived at it:

I added an `output` block so I could see what I was working with and I commented out the problematic lines in my terraform file so I could successfully execute `terraform apply`. Next I ran `terraform apply` followed by `terraform output --json` (note: the `apply` must be successful for `output` to have the latest values).

Example temporary output block:

```
output "test" {
  value = "${data.aws_cognito_user_pools.test}" // output top-level object for debugging
}
```

Relevant `terraform apply` output:

```json
test = {
  "arns" = [
    "<redacted>",
  ]
  "id" = "a_name"
  "ids" = [
    "us-east-1_<redacted>",
  ]
  "name" = "a_name"
}
```

Relevant `terraform output --json` output:

```json
"test": {
  "sensitive": false,
  "type": [
    "object",
    {
      "arns": [
        "set",
        "string"
      ],
      "id": "string",
      "ids": [
        "set",
        "string"
      ],
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "value": {
    "arns": [
      "<redacted>"
    ],
    "id": "a_name",
    "ids": [
      "us-east-1_<redacted>"
    ],
    "name": "a_name"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `ids` portion is a `set` of type `string`. I decided to try converting `ids` to a list to see if I could then access the `0` index and it worked. I feel like this could be a terraform bug, but I haven't filed an issue yet.

Comment: Please add "}" to the first example to complete string interpolation in the output test block.